# Unable to upgrade React Native

Tags: react-native

i try to upgrade my react native project to the newest version.

When i try to run `npx react-native upgrade` i get the error:

```
error Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@0.69.1 react@18.0.0

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.69.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.69.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"> 0.57" from @fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome@0.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome
npm ERR!     @fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome@"^0.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   24 more (@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider, ...)
```

Anybody may had the same problem?
My current version is 0.63.4.

Tanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can upgrade your project's react native version. But I would suggest to go by the following link [React Native upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.4&to=0.69.1), then run`npm i --save` or `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` if any issue, do ask.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your network settings and update DNS to 8.8.8.8 and you will be able to update RN version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).